# Show a WP 3.0 Custom Menu in an HTML Select with Auto-Navigation?

Tags: customization, themes, theme-development, menus

As part of a theme for a client, **I want to be able to show a custom menu** (defined via the admin) **in a select box that automatically changes pages after changing the selection**.

Is there a plugin (or a handy code snippet) that will accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**WordPress' new menu system is both wondrous and infinitely frustrating**, depending on what you are trying to do and what day of the week it happens to be. :) It's a great idea but far from mature so while it's a feature I applaud I'll be happier when v3.3 or v3.4 of WordPress rolls out and we get a lot more use-cases directly supported by the menu system's API.

That said, not sure if there is an existing plugin to do what you are looking for, but **how about the code you need to write you own plugin?** Or you could just include it in your theme's `functions.php` file; whatever your preference.

What I'm providing is a fully self-contained example that you can save as `test.php`in your website's root directory in order to test it. If your domain were `example.com` you'd load to test at:

> `http://example.com/test.php`

Here's what it look's like in action:

[image: Inactive drop down of Pages from WordPress 3.0 Menu]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20100825-005514.png))</sub>
[image: Active drop down of Pages from WordPress 3.0 Menu]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20100825-005345.png))</sub>

From the code below it should be easy to incorporate the `get_page_selector()` function into your theme and to call it whenever you need this functionality:

```
<?php

  include "wp-load.php";
  echo 'Jump to:';
  echo get_page_selector('My Select Menu');

function get_page_selector($menu) {
  $page_menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu,array(
    'meta_key'=>'_menu_item_object',
    'meta_value'=>'page',
  ));
  $selector = array();
  if (is_array($page_menu_items) && count($page_menu_items)>0) {
    $selector[] =<<<HTML
<select id="page-selector" name="page-selector"
    onchange="location.href = document.getElementById('page-selector').value;">
HTML;
    $selector[] = '<option value="">Select a Page</option>';
    foreach($page_menu_items as $page_menu_item) {
      $link = get_page_link($page_menu_item->object_id);
      $selector[] =<<<HTML
<option value="{$link}">{$page_menu_item->title}</option>
HTML;
  }
    $selector[] = '</select>';
  }
  return implode("\n",$selector);
}
```

So you might wonder how it works?

### The `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` function

WordPress 3.0 stores it's menus in the `wp_posts` table as `post_type` type of `nav_menu_item`. The `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` indirectly just calls the `get_posts()` function. The first parameter to `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` is either 1.) a menu name (which is what I used: *"My Select Menu"*), 2.) a menu item ID (i.e. the menu item's post `ID` the database) or 3.) a menu slug (the slug from the menu's taxonomy term; yes menus are implemented using taxonomy terms with a taxonomy of `'nav_menu'`.)

[image: Menu Configuration in WordPress 3.0]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20100825-010542.png))</sub>

Beyond the first parameter it forwards on to `get_posts()` most (if not all?) of the `$args` you pass to `wp_get_nav_menu_items()` thus you can treat it like a custom post type (even though longer term when they improve the menu API that probably won't be such a great idea. But today? Make hay while the sun shines!)

### Filtering Menu Items with `meta_key` and `meta_value`

WordPress' underlying use of posts for menu items is why we can query for `meta_key` and `meta_value`; WordPress uses a series of `meta_keys` prefixed with `_menu_item` for the additional information it needs for each menu item. `_menu_item_object` will contain `page` for every menu item that corresponds to a WordPress *"Page"* post type. (If you want to include items besides Pages you you'll need to do a bit more research than I did here but at least I gave you the tools you need to do the research yourself.)

Here's a screenshot using [Navicat for MySQL](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql) of a query showing the meta records for several `nav_menu_items`:

[image: Menu Item Configuration found in wp_postmeta with WordPress 3.0]
<sub>(source: [mikeschinkel.com](https://mikeschinkel.com/websnaps/skitched-20100825-011357.png))</sub>

### Grabbing the Page's URL with `get_post_link()`

Next I'll point out that get the page's URL from the `get_post_link()` function and that I'm setting the HTML `<option>`'s `value` to be the URL...

```
<?php
    $link = get_page_link($page_menu_item->object_id);
    $selector[] =<<<HTML
<option value="{$link}">{$page_menu_item->title}</option>
HTML;
```

### Using Javascript's `onchange` to Navigate to our Selected Page

...So that I can grab it from the `value` property of the `'page-selector'` `<select>` element and assign it to `location.href`. Assigning `location.href` causes the browser to immediately navigate to the new URL, and that, in a nutshell, is how it's all done:

```
<?php
  $selector[] =<<<HTML
<select id="page-selector" name="page-selector"
    onchange="location.href = document.getElementById('page-selector').value;">
HTML;
```

### An Empty `value=""` as the Default Option

You might note that the *"Select a Page"* default option has an empty value; that's not a mistake but instead by design. When it is selected and the `"onchange"` is triggered<sup>**1**</sup>  setting `location.href` to an empty string will have no effect, which is exactly what we want and it doesn't require us to write an exception code. *Viola!*

```
<?php
    $selector[] = '<option value="">Select a Page</option>';
```

1. Having selection of *"Select a Page"* trigger `"onchange"` can only happen on a browser back navigation to a page that doesn't trigger a page reload where another option had previously been selected, but it can still happen so we should address it.

Comment: Holy crap! :)

Thanks for the lesson Mike.  I think this will work just fine in my case.  I don't know about wrapping it in a plugin at this point, but who knows...it may just end up there.  If it does, you'll of course get credit... :)

Thanks for the title edit too...I was a bit frazzled when I wrote it, so I wasn't exactly thinking clearly... :)

Comment: Hmmm...apparently, something is wrong here...when I add the function to my functions.php file, I get the following:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /media/storage/swd/wp-content/themes/theme2/functions.php on line 55

line 55 is the $selector[] line in the foreach...

Comment: @Keith S.: Do you have any menu items for pages defined in your site yet? My code didn't protect against having zero menu items for pages (but I just updated the code to address that.) Did you make sure you used the correct menu name from your site? Did you ensure that the `HTML;` lines are *NOT INDENTED?*, i.e. that they are flush left with no spaces to the left of the `HTML`? Any chance your site is running on PHP4? (I don't know if this would matter, but it might.) In case you had a cut and paste error, here the code is where you can more easily copy it. http://gist.github.com/550217

Comment: I had menu items set up, tried all sorts of indentation, but in the end, I would up doing this (which works fine...and for the record, I'm running php 5.3 on my dev server)... http://pastie.textmate.org/private/haynxduumjwxn8jdjtktq

Comment: @Keith S. - Look like you just dropped the filter on post_type=='page' which wasn't required by I did ironically to simplify things. But since it works for you without, go for it!

Comment: Yeah, I needed an option as a default, but I couldn't code it into the function because the theme I'm working on is going to have three of these running on the sidebar, so I added a custom link with a javascript:void(0) target.

But yeah, after switching to traditional strings in the function, everything works great.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Keith S. Glad I could help.

Comment: By some amazing stroke of good fortune, exactly what my customer has asked for as well. Great stuff, Mike.

Comment: Hey @Tony B. Glad I could help, thanks for the kudos. The irony is that frequently what people ask for are often the same as what other's need.