# How to make navigation a <select> list without a plugin?

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show a WP 3.0 Custom Menu in an HTML Select with Auto-Navigation?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/859/show-a-wp-3-0-custom-menu-in-an-html-select-with-auto-navigation)

I have tried several solution for this, but none of them worked.
I managed to make the nav list into `<select><option>` list, but without only with names of the pages, without any indication of their URL

Any ideas how can I make a fully functional select list navigation without an external plugin?

(The ideal solution would be the pages URLs would appear as a `value` in the `option` so I can use JavaScript for page navigation)

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate question of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55856/select-menu-on-browser-resize/55889#55889 Check my answer there.

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can add onclick event on each option

```
<select>
<option onClick="go_to_url" value="http://google.com">Google</option>
</select>
```

and you have to make JS function go_to_url making window.location.href = this.value;